# How to handle race condition when updating state and also changing route in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So I have a chat app where I can access different chat rooms. When I'm in one of the chat rooms, I can change chat rooms by clicking on the other chat rooms (just like how WhatsApp and other chat apps behaves). So I have a function which handles clicking on the other chat room as such:

```js
const handleChatClick = () => {
   closeAllDocks(dispatch);
   history.push(`/chats/${chat.id}`);
};
```

So in my app, I have something called "Docks". For example, I can open the chat room profile page, and it'll be opened as a "Dock" on the right side (split screen). So when I want to change chat room, I want to make sure that all of these docks are closed. This is where the `closeAllDocks(dispatch)` function comes in. In this case, `dispatch` is basically `const dispatch = useDispatch()` from redux. So when this gets called, all the docks' state will be set to `false`.

However, the issue is that, when I run this function, the `history.push(...)` will get executed, and the `closeAllDocks(dispatch)` as well, but I guess `history.push(...)` will finish executing first. This causes some sort of delay, where I can see the content of the dock gets changed according to the new chat room (even though it's only for a split second) then closes.

How should I be handling this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trick/hack I've had to use in the past to solve issues similar to this is to place the navigation action in a short timeout so it's placed at the end of Javascript's event loop and allows the dispatched actions to process and React to rerender once then the navigation can be effected.

Example:

```js
const handleChatClick = () => {
  closeAllDocks(dispatch);
  setTimeout(() => history.push(`/chats/${chat.id}`), 0);
  // or setTimeout(history.push, 0, `/chats/${chat.id}`);
};
```

An alternative might be to make your "close all docks" action/logic asynchronous, e.g. a `createAsyncThunk`, so you can await it in the UI code.

Example:

```js
const closeAllDocks => dispatch => dispatch(closeAllDocksAsyncAction());
```

```js
const handleChatClick = async () => {
  await closeAllDocks(dispatch);
  history.push(`/chats/${chat.id}`);
};
```